# Google Place API Limit - NOT usage limit

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I've managed to get Google Places up and running, but there seems to be a limit on the number of country variables I can add. I'm basing my code on one of their samples:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-hotelsearch

But every time I try to add a country to the `var countries` section and reload the page I get a blank page, with just a drop down menu and some text at the bottom.

Is there a limit to the number of country variables I can add to Google Places?

UPDATE:

Adding extra countries.

The javascript is the same as in the above example:

```
var map, places, infoWindow; 
 var markers = []; 
 var autocomplete; var countryRestrict = { 'country': 'uk' };
 var MARKER_PATH = 'maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/marker_green'; 
 var hostnameRegexp = new RegExp('^https?://.+?/');
 var countries = { 
 'at': { 
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.5, 14.5), 
 zoom: 6 }, 
 'be': { 
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.5, 4.4),
 zoom: 6 },
```

Then within the HTML there's a drop down menu:

```
<div id="controls"> 
<select id="country"> 
<option value="at">Austria</option>
```

I'm pretty sure it's not a coding issue, more that it seems to stop working when more than 18 countries are included.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?  What happens if you remove one country and the add another?

Comment: I just tried it with 19 countries and it appears to work.

Comment: Removing one country and adding another isn't a problem. As soon as I add an extra country though I get two error messages in the console: 1. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string` 2. `Uncaught ReferenceError: initialize is not defined`. The second error refers to the first body tag `<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">`

Comment: Do you have a function names initialize? is the first error in the initialize function?

Comment: Yep I have an initialize function which works fine until an extra country is added. But that is the second error. The first error is the syntax error and points to `'us': {`. But I can't see any syntax error as this is the same syntax as previous countries in the list.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you post the bit of code with the extra country that you managed to get working so I can compare to mine. I expect it's something really small that I've missed.

Comment: My only thought on the error with 'us' : { is that you may have removed the comma that is supposed to go after the proceeding country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about the delay.

```
var countries = {
  'at': { 
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.0, 14.5), 
    zoom: 6 }, 
  'be': { 
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.5, 4.4),
    zoom: 6 },
  'cz': { 
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.817492, 15.472962), 
    zoom: 6 }, 
  'bz': { 
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(17.189877, -88.497650),
    zoom: 6 },
  'hn': { 
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(15.199999, -86.241905), 
    zoom: 6 }, 
  'cr': { 
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(9.748917, -83.753428),
    zoom: 6 },
  'co': { 
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(4.570868, -74.297333),
    zoom: 6 },
  'au': {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.3, 133.8),
    zoom: 4
  },
  'br': {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-14.2, -51.9),
    zoom: 3
  },
  'ca': {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(62, -110.0),
    zoom: 3
  },
  'fr': {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.2, 2.2),
    zoom: 5
  },
  'de': {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.2, 10.4),
    zoom: 5
  },
  'mx': {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.6, -102.5),
    zoom: 4
  },
  'nz': {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-40.9, 174.9),
    zoom: 5
  },
  'it': {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.9, 12.6),
    zoom: 5
  },
  'za': {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-30.6, 22.9),
    zoom: 5
  },
  'es': {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.5, -3.7),
    zoom: 5
  },
  'pt': {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.4, -8.2),
    zoom: 6
  },
  'us': {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.1, -95.7),
    zoom: 3
  },
  'uk': {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.8, -4.6),
    zoom: 5
  }
};
```

And the html:

```
<div id="controls">
      <select id="country">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="bz">Belize</option>
        <option value="cz">Czech Republic</option>
        <option value="hn">Honduras</option>
        <option value="cr">Costa Rica</option>
        <option value="co">Colombia</option>
        <option value="at">Austria</option>
        <option value="be">Belgium</option>
        <option value="au">Australia</option>
        <option value="br">Brazil</option>
        <option value="ca">Canada</option>
        <option value="fr">France</option>
        <option value="de">Germany</option>
        <option value="mx">Mexico</option>
        <option value="nz">New Zealand</option>
        <option value="it">Italy</option>
        <option value="za">South Africa</option>
        <option value="es">Spain</option>
        <option value="pt">Portugal</option>
        <option value="us" selected>U.S.A.</option>
        <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Great, thanks for that, seems to have done the trick, though for the life of me I still can't see what was wrong in the first place. Probably been staring at it for too long by this point. Much appreciated.